# How are (string[] args) passed to Program.Main in a Blazor WebAssembly app?

Tags: blazor, webassembly

The `Program.Main` method in a Blazor WASM app has `string[] args` parameter. Is it possible for the ASP.NET Core host site to pass arguments into these? I need to be able to read a value from the server *before* the app has been built.

Comment: Have you considered using environment variables?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Program.Main` is invoked by `blazor.webassembly.js` [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/2d0c49d0fca0aaf37672e0aec1c011cfe6a2d6f2/src/Components/Web.JS/src/Platform/Mono/MonoPlatform.ts#L40):

```
invokeEntrypoint(assemblyName, null);
```

which hits a [dotnet static method](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/e1bf38ccaf2a98f95e48bf22b8b76d996a0c33ea/src/Components/Blazor/Blazor/src/Hosting/EntrypointInvoker.cs#L18) which then turns the null into an empty array.

So no, it's not possible to pass arguments to it right now because you only ever get an empty array.

Comment: Of course, the correct approach now is to use app config :)

Comment: It's a bit tricky if you're doing something dynamic, like per-tenant config

Answer (score 7):

There is no default way to pass these parameters in, because indeed they are hardcoded to be null in `blazor.webassembly.js`. It is however possible to provide them via javascript.

In your index page, include the following:

```
<!-- Put this script block above the one that loads blazor.webassembly.js -->
<script>
    window.startupParams = function() { return ['first', 'second', 'third']; };
</script>
```

In your Program.cs:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
    var js = (IJSInProcessRuntime)builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IJSRuntime>();
    var startupParams = js.Invoke<string[]>("startupParams");

    // ... etc ...
}
```

As found in this [github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24461#issuecomment-667068936) answer.

We serve the index page from asp.net core, as an index.cshtml page. And have logic on the server-side to populate the array in the script with the needed parameters.

Comment: That is actually clever.